# how to configure no passsword with OpenVPN on systemd for a backup script

Tags: debian, systemd, openvpn

I have a backup script that will initiate an OpenVPN connection using `systemctl stop openvpn@myvpn`. It works fine if I run that command on the command line but it asks for a username and password. Is there anyway to securely save the username and password somewhere so I can automate/script the connecting/disconnecting?

```
root@host:/# systemctl start openvpn@myvpn
Enter Auth Username: *****************
Enter Auth Password: *****************
```

Comment: `man openvpn | less -p auth-user-pass`...

Comment: @jasonwryan If you can put that in an answer then I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

We use the OpenVPN Access Server, which has the GUI. If you are using the same, you can enable auto login profiles for users. Downloading the client.ovpn file with auto-login will no longer require you to enter your username and password.

I haven't done it through CLI before, but if you have access to the admin page on the GUI do:

Login -> User Permissions -> Find the user -> Enable auto-login

Then login as the user, and download their client.ovpn. Inside it will say

```
OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_PROFILE=user@VPN.ADDRESS/AUTOLOGIN
```